# Is it possible to set date intervals for news post?

Tags: php, joomla

I have news on site about some events so I would like to set starting and ending date for them. For example: "27 Feb - 04 Mar: Free icons at church gates".
Is it possible and if yes can I have any tip how to do it?

Comment: I might not remember Joomla very well, but this doesn't seem like a programming question to me. Can you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Within the Article Editor, open the *Publishing* tab.
2. Enter your start and end dates into the appropriate fields.
3. Save the article.

Your article will be published in the period of time you specified.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I already know about this. I asked is it possible to set smth opposite to "Created date" so on news page users could see starting and ending date of event.

Comment: You can use a template override to display the `publish_up` and `publish_down` dates, but that might not be what you want, because you maybe want to publish the article before the event starts in order to promote the event. In that case, you should consider to use an event component - there is a lot of them in the extension directory.